# Sharing folder on Ubuntu 9.10 VM with Windows 7 as host

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have read through several guide but im having trouble getting it working. I have installed the Guest Addition, cause my mouse integration works. However, when I shared my folder and restart the OS. I see nothing in my Ubuntu desktop. How can I find the shared folder?

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 2):

It's really easy: you should have searched VBox's manuals for "shared". The solution is to open Windows "console" via "cmd.exe" and type there:

In a Linux guest, use the following command:

> mount -t vboxsf [-o OPTIONS] sharename mountpoint

If you were using a Windows guest OS, it would have looked like this:

> net use x:\\vboxsvr\Share

Where "x" is the mount virtual drive letter, "Share" is the shared folder name.

Cheers! :)

Comment: hmmmm, assuming my shared folder name is "desktop_win7" what's shoudl i put as mountpoint in ubuntu?

Comment: `mkdir /media/anything && mount -t vboxsf "desktop_win7" /media/anything` ;)

Comment: Typo in Windows portion (two preceding backslashes): net use x: \\vboxsvr\Share

Comment: Thanks! Not a typo really, it's SuperUser parser that ate two backslashes :)

Comment: For those of you who are still having problems it might be you're missing the following packages: dkms, build-essential, and linux-headers-generic. [read more](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15679)


try running: `sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic` then reboot. After reboot mount the share like mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a detail answer from this website :)

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/11/25/how-to-access-windows-host-shared-folders-from-linux-ubuntu-guest-os-virtual-machine/